# How do you render the fetched data in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to read the json data from url, put it in an empty array, put it in a react component, and print it out.
However, if you put the json data in the result array and output it as console.log, only the empty array is output.
Is it wrong to push the array?

Also, I want to repeat this url 100 times and print it out in the order of many counts.
For example, count: 15 {Json content}.
Thank you.

> let result = [];
>
> fetch("http:// ~ ").then(res => {
> return res.json()}).then(data =>
> result.push(data)).then(()=>console.log(result));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The last `.then` is redundant. Put the `console.log(result)` in the same function as `result.push(data)` and it should work. You do need to add brackets to the function, though, since it will no longer be a "one-liner".

```
fetch("http:// ~ ")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    result.push(data);
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Edit: The way that `.then` works is that it executes once a promise is resolved. `res.json()` returns a promise. Your own function (`data => result.push(data)`) does not return a promise. So using `.then` on your own function doesn't make any sense. I hope this clears things up for you.

Edit 2:

Since this is in react, you shouldn't do `let result = []` and `result.push(data)`. Instead, you should do something like this:

```
const [result, setResult] = React.useState();
```

And within your own function, change `result.push(data)` to this:

```
setResult([...result, data]);
```

Comment: thanks!
but still put the fetched data in the result array outside and open it to the console.log from the fetch outside, still get an empty array.
How do i solve this problem?

Comment: You're using react, so I would suspect that you need to use `useState`. I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use useEffect and or useState hook to trigger a rerender.

```
let result = [];

useEffect(()=>{
fetch("http:// ~ ")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    result.push(data);
    console.log(result);
  });
},[])
```

not this will trigger a re-render once your data is fetched

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => { 
      fetch("http:// ~ ")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setState([...state, data]));
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
  );
}
```